# Duplicate Connection:keep-alive, Keep-Alive

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers

I am using PageSpeed Insights for Chrome to test my webpage & it suggest that I should enable Connection keep-alive. Although the headers in apache were set by default to Keep Alive I manually set them using my .htaccess file using the code below.

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
```

And now when I check the response header of each & every resource from the chrome dev tools the response header contains `Connection:keep-alive, Keep-Alive`. The keep alive is repeated twice, how do I prevent this from happening. A .htaccess solution is required because I don't have access to the apache or php setup files.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Apache Module mod_headers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) doc, example 6 :

> Set the same header value under multiple nonexclusive conditions, but do not duplicate the value in the final header. If all of the following conditions applied to a request (i.e., if the CGI, NO_CACHE and NO_STORE environment variables all existed for the request):

```
Header merge Cache-Control no-cache env=CGI
Header merge Cache-Control no-cache env=NO_CACHE
Header merge Cache-Control no-store env=NO_STORE
```

> then the response would contain the following header:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
```

> If append was used instead of merge, then the response would contain the following header:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-cache, no-store
```

I hope this can help.